# Storing the direction of normals to have the desired shader's look

Tags: normals

Good morning community. I would like to ask if there is a way to store the direction of the normals (similar to  vertex group) , so that the model can have its normals switched to the way I want the shade looks.

Comment: Hello. You should add more details about how are these custom normals and from which data you've them.

Comment: tbh i dnt understand the comment since english is not my native language. What i wish to know, is if i can have the normals of a face stored into several grps (similar to vertex grp on object data), and having their directions saved so that i can access them depending the way i want the shadow to look.

Comment: Vertex groups are not accessible from the shader node tree. You can acces to vertex colors. Can that be a way for you?